# Express.js POST req.body empty

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, body-parser

So I have the following code in my server.js file that I'm running with node.js. I'm using express to handle HTTP requests.

```
app.post('/api/destinations', function (req, res) {
  var new_destination = req.body;
  console.log(req.body);
  console.log(req.headers);
  db.Destination.create(new_destination, function(err, destination){
    if (err){
      res.send("Error: "+err);
    }
    res.json(destination);
  });
});
```

I'm running the following in Terminal:

```
curl -XPOST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"location": "New York","haveBeen": true,"rating": 4}' http://localhost:3000/api/destinations
```

After running that server.js prints out the following.

```
{}
{ host: 'localhost:3000',
  'user-agent': 'curl/7.43.0',
  accept: '*/*',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'content-length': '53' }
```

So req.body is `{}`. I read other Stack Overflow posts about similar issues where content-type was not correct because of body-parser. But that isn't the issue because content-type is application/json.

Any ideas how to get the actual body of the request?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You do use the body-parser middleware, right?

Comment: And if you are: how, exactly?

Comment: I am using body-parser. Basically just requiring it then "app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));" without the quotes of course.

Comment: `urlencoded()` does _not_ handle `application/json` ([hint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#bodyparserjsonoptions)).

Comment: Thank you so much @robertklep adding bodyParser.json() fixed it. Can't believe I forgot that.... thanks so much

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need bodyParser.json as well:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks so much!! Can't believe I forgot that.

Comment: Thank you! Not sure why but when I tried `app.use(bodyParser.json());
` after reading your comment, it worked, even though I tried it many times before. Must be a magic answer ;)

Comment: I am still having an empty body despite both lines being included. Not sure why.

Comment: I have done everything you guys advice here, but nothing works. I wonder why this error happen? please good answers!

Comment: Works fine for me: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/72e0e5af4ad10152e90cfccdcb62b836

Comment: You're telling me a f(*&#@@( web framework won't allow me to access data passed in via a POST unless I extend it?!

Comment: Make sure to `JSON.stringify()` the data

Comment: I'm actually curious why this isn't the default too?

Comment: Newer versions of express require an updated approach:

`app.use(express.json());`
`app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`

Also, some answers suggest not using serialize on the browser/client side. Using jQuery, serialize was the only way I got it to work. Stringified payload does not get parsed as expected on the server side.

Answer (score 16):

Sometimes the req.body shows {} if you forgot to put the name attribute to the form input fields. Following is an example:

```
<input type="email" name="myemail" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Email address" required>
```

Then the req.body shows `{ myemail: 'mathewjohnxxxx@gmail.com' }`

I post this answer because, i have encountered the similar problem and this worked for me.

Comment: i was wondering why the body parser only works with "name" attributes in inputs, not just "id". This answer helps me a lot, sometimes we just forgot these basic things. Ps: In .NET, I never used names in input fields, so this was unusual to me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure if you are making the form and inputs in javascript that you append the input to the form. That was my issue.

```
yourForm.appendChild(yourInput);
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the back end was configured properly the issue was valid JSON format including double quotes on the variables.

this did not work

```js
      const res = await axios.post(serverPath + "/user/login", {
         email: email,
         password: password,
      });
```

This **DID** work (with double quotes around email and password

```js
      const res = await axios.post(serverPath + "/user/login", {
         "email": email,
         "password": password,
      });
```

Comment: For JavaScript, `{"email": email, "password": password}` is identical to `{email: email, password: password}`

Comment: I agree with you but for what ever reason when axios was parsing this the result was one worked and one did not.  I don't have an explanation - just posting in the even that it may save someone time.