# Sending JSON data to server with Expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an html form that has several fields which I package in a JSON, and I need to send this to a server. I have the  following code on the front end:

```
var data = {
//data here
};
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST","localhost:8000/add",true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
xhr.send(data);
```

And then on the server, I have this code to receive it:

```
app.post('/add', function(req,res) {
  console.log(req.body.name);
  res.json(req.body.name);
});
```

It sends nothing; what do I need to do to get it to send the  JSON?

Comment: Are you using the body parser?

Comment: Did you try to check req.body (console.log(req.body);) to see if you received any data or not ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Express.js POST req.body empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38294730/express-js-post-req-body-empty)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `body-parser` to get values in `req.body`

From [npm documents](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#examples)

> ```
> var express = require('express')
> var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
>
> var app = express()
>
> // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
>
> // parse application/json
> app.use(bodyParser.json())
> ```

Comment: I included those, and still nothing gets sent.

Answer (score 0):

You are not handling the response of post request,and also make sure you are using body parser at backend. So you front end code should be like this:

```
var data = {name:"xyz"};
var json = JSON.stringify(data);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST","localhost:8000/add",true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json; charset=utf-8');
xhr.onload = function () {
    var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
   if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == "201") {
    console.log(data);
  } else {
    console.log(data);
  }
}
xhr.send(json);
```

And your server side code should be coded like :

```
 var express = require('express')
   var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

   var app = express();
   // parse application/json
   app.use(bodyParser.json())

  // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

    app.post('/add', function(req,res) {
      console.log(req.body.name);
      res.status(201).json(req.body.name);
  });
```

Comment: this is now all blocked by CORS policy

Answer (score 0):

I tested it with this code and it success with me:

Client code same as your code.

Server Code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/add', function(req,res) {
  console.log(req.body.name);
  res.json(req.body.name);
});
```