# Ajax call results in 500 {internal server error}

Tags: ajax

I am trying to send json data through ajax call. 
Following is the code I used. I'm using node.js as the backend. a_filters,b_filters,etc. are arrays. I googled the error but couldn't get the code to work.

```
var filters =
                {
                    "a" : a_filters,
                    "b" : b_filters,
                    "c" : c_filters,
                    "d" : d_filters
                };
        $.ajax({
            url : "query/get-filtered-data",
            dataType : 'json',
            async: "true",
            data:JSON.stringify(filters),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success : function(data){


            },
            failure: function(data){
                alert('got an error');
            }
        });
```

**EDIT :  This is my server-side code.**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

//the URL below is correct since it redirects from 'query/'
router.get('/get-filtered-data', function (req, res, next) {

    console.log(req);    
    var filters = JSON.parse(req.body);
    console.log("foo");
    var a_filters = filters["a"];
    var b_filters = filters["b"];
    var c_filters = filters["c"];
    var d_filters = filters["d"];

    res.send(query);
});
```

`conosle.log('foo')` doesn't print anything. 
`console.log(req)` has req.body empty. 
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: 500 means the error occurred at the server end so you need to look at the logs there, or share that code.

Comment: I've added the server side code. Please have a look

Comment: you should use body-parser for Node.js json handling. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38294910/2143734

Comment: Get wouldn't expect a body, you would need post or put

Comment: So I'm guessing the error occurs when you reference req.body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are referencing req.body, you need to use a router method that includes a body - post or put.

You may also need to include type: "POST" in your jQuery Ajax method.

There is a more general semantic question about whether you should use get with a query string to communicate parameters when retrieving data rather than using a request body, but that is an API design question rather than a cause of errors.